# oracle function for escaping

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like to know if there is an Oracle function to escape special characters.

Here is the example :

```
request := 'update tvire set nbqe = ''' || var_my_value  
dbms_sql.parse(curseur_ref_2, request, dbms_sql.native);
response := dbms_sql.execute(curseur_ref_2);
```

if var_my_value contains quotes, there is an error during execution.

Is there an Oracle function that prevent that : xx(var_my_value)

thank you

Comment: Basically you can do something like this: `request := 'update tvire set nbqe = q''[' || var_my_value || ']''';`. But don't, as you should use use bind variables as @WW pointed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't attempt to escape, instead use *bind variables*.

Answer (score 0):

Use bind variables and execute immediate:

`execute immediate update t1 set c1 = :p1 where c2 = :p2 using var_my_value1, var_my_value2`

dbms_sql should be used only in rare cases. For example when dynamic query has varying number of parameters.

PS: even dbms_sql has procedure `bind_variable`.